# MySQL db design for products

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am developing a web application that will allow people to keep track of products that they will move around.

Example: 
I have 10 cups in my warehouse. I move 5 cups to ShopA and 5 cups to ShopB. I then move 3 cups from ShopA back to my warehouse.

In terms of my db structure, i thought of having a products table that looked something like this:
product_id
location_id
quantity

But it seems a little clumsy. In the example i would have 1 record in products table for this product, then 2, then 3.

My question is:
Is it better in this case to have 10 rows (1 row per item instead of a quantity field) for this product and change location of each product? But if this table stores the products for lots of users, in a very short period of time, the table will have millions of rows... should i be worried about that?

I am very interested in what is considered the best practice in this kind of situation.

thank you!

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I have decided to go with a concurrency method and store the quantity instead of one row per item. My table would quickly have gotten too big to manage. I am going to use an audit table to track the movement of the products and run queries on that rather. thanks again!

Comment: You have just decided to do both, but do them in the worst way.

Comment: hey, sorry, did i miss something? How can i run fast queries on a table with 50 billion rows? The audit table would only need to be checked if there is a problem.

Comment: The "concurrency" method is very dangerous, because it has problems with race conditions.  You could use a materialized view to store the "de-normalized" data.  http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Comment: Anyways, 50 billion rows is not bad, *with proper indexing*.  Indexes let you look at just the rows you need, searching for them with a binary search.  That plus materialized views is definitely the way I would go.

Comment: wow, thanks John. I didnt consider race conditions, this would definitely be a issue. I knew indexes were powerful but i didnt realize that it would allow me to have a table that large. I will go with your suggestion of one row per product. thanks so much for your time

Comment: Good to hear, you may end up still using a "de-normailzed" version of the data for quick analytics, but that should be done as-needed (rather than up-front).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ollie Jones' answer, but I would like to add that the "Double Entry Bookkeeping" method would be to have rows like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Transactions] (
    [FromLocationId] /* foreign key to the locations */,
    [ToLocationId] /* ditto */,
    [Amount]
)
```

This way, there is only one row per transaction.

Answer (score 2):

The question is this: What items in your inventory have a unique identity?
Does each cup have a distinct barcode on it? (never mind cups; let's talk about books).

If your items have unique identifiers (their own barcodes or RFID tags) you definitely need a row for each item.  As you acquire, relocate, or sell each item you'll update its row to reflect its new location.

For example, consider books in a library.  Each book is unique.  Even if the library owns two copies of the book, they are handled separately.

On the other hand, if the items are interchangeable, like copies of books in a bookstore, then you can make the simplifying assumption that you can have an item count for each item for each location.  The book store has five copies of the latest Harry Potter on the shelf.  When a customer buys one, the bookstore now has four copies. When the bookstore receives another boxful, it how has 14 copies.

Of course, the two approaches are quite different in the nature of the DBMS transaction that takes place when you relocate inventory.  The second approach looks more like double entry bookkeeping, and the first like a census of products.

Considering how cheap data storage is these days, and the proliferation of unique identifiers like RFID tags, you are probably better off using the first approach, with a row for each item.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. The products would be identical (10 copies of a book), but would only have different locations. If i had a row for each individual item and 100k users each with 5k products with 100 of each product, i would have 50 Billion rows in the table, would this be a problem?

Comment: Yes, 5 x 10**10 rows is too many to be smart.  But...that is a lot of stuff.  Even if these products are worth $0.01 each, you are talking about $500 million worth of inventory. I hope you enjoy such business success, but in the meantime are you overestimating your capacity requirements?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simple question is do you want easier programability, or a smaller database?  With storage as cheap as it is now, and only getting cheaper, the answer is clear: save yourself significant heartburn and build your database in a manner that gives you the simplest code in the future.

Comment: I would agree.  Millions of rows == TENS OF MEGABYTES!

Answer (score 1):

If your save 1 row per item:

- No concurerency locks. Fast insert/delete item. Simplest design.

If save item with quantity:

- Concurency update is more complex. For avoid blocks we added new field in table and verify/set it before every update.

[Millions of rows - not problem for MySQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?711911-Searching-on-38-million-records.-How-can-I-speed-up-the-return-of-results&s=7943a96a7eb1034e1851724cb0d8870b)

See also **NoSQL-store**: maybe above efficient for your.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score -1):

In my opnion whatever the situation -> you have just two ways to follow:

- concurerency
- no concurerency

In short words it mean, you are going to record a lot of lines in your database or just record the Quantity of that item.

Partiulary I prefer to record only the quantity of that item (using concurerency), it is sometimes more complex to manage, but a good routine to take care of it, will give you no trouble at all in the future, because your database will not grow up if you are not going to use concurerency.

But of course, mysql can hold easily milions of rows without a problem, It is up to you to decide the best aprouch.

Forecast your databse growth, measure it, if the database will grow up a lot in a short span of time, then is better you go with concurerency method.

Good Luck!